# Splitting a string of a specific format to floats and strings

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I have a project where the input is in a specific format and need to extract data from it.

The format is similar to `H79.03 = J99.30`, and I need to get the floats.

How is the best way to do this using only `std::stringstream` and `std::string`?

Comment: What did you try so far ?  Post your code.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you can use only stringstream and string. First, replace invalid digits by spaces. Then take the numbers.

```
string originalStr = "H79.03 = J99.30";
string expression = originalStr;
for(int i = 0; i < expression.length(); i++) {
    if (!isdigit(expression[i]) && (expression[i] != '.'))
         expression[i] = ' ';
}
stringstream str(expression);
float firstValue, secondValue;
str >> firstValue;
str >> secondValue;

cout<<firstValue<<endl; // it prints 79.03
cout<<secondValue<<endl; // it prints 99.30
```

Comment: Your loop is replacing the decimal points of the floats. Don't convert those to spaces. And `firstValue` and `secondValue` need to be declared as `float` or `double` instead of `int`

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau for your suggestions.

Comment: you are still discarding the decimal points. `isdigit()` returns false for `'.'`. You need to use this instead: `if (!isdigit(expression[i]) && (expression[i] != '.'))`

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string s = "H79.03 = J99.30";
std::istringstream iss(s);
double d1, d2;

if (iss.ignore() &&
    iss >> d1 &&
    iss.ignore(4) &&
    iss >> d2)
{
    // is d1 and d2 as needed...
}
```

[Live Demo](https://www.ideone.com/hylw92)